# Show Image or Text on a column depending on the type of the rowobject in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, object, objectlistview

i'm using a FastObjectListView that can contain two different types of objects. It could be an object from type `Testaction` or from `Milestone`. If it is an object from type `Testaction` there is a property called `Successful` on which i decide whether to show a green or a red image. If the object is from type `Milestone` there is a property `Result` which is a %-Number. Now i want to be able to show a image or that %-number in the same column.

```
this.olvColumn9.ImageGetter = delegate(object rowObject)
        {
                Testaction action = rowObject as Testaction;
                if (action.Successful)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        };
```

This is setting the image to the column. The images are stored in a ImageList. But i just don't know how to set a text into the column if it's not from type `Testaction`.

I would be grateful for any help.

Relax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the object type is `Milestone` it should work to return NULL from the ImageGetter handler and to return the respective string from the AspectGetter of the column.

Something like this (code not checked for syntax and function):

```
this.olvColumn9.ImageGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    if (rowObject is Testaction) {
        Testaction action = rowObject as Testaction;
            if (action.Successful) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

this.olvColumn9.AspectGetter = delegate(object rowObject) {
    if (rowObject is Milestone) {
        return ((Milestone)rowObject).Result.ToString();
    }
};
```